# CoffeeScript - problems passing args to super constructor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following CoffeeScript code:

```
planet = new Planet p5, {x: 100, y: 100, diameter: 20}
```

and somewhere else:

```
class GameObject
  constructor: (@p5, @x, @y) ->
    @selected = false

class Planet extends GameObject
  constructor: (p5, opts) ->
    super (p5 opts.x opts.y)
    @diameter = opts.diameter
```

and for the `super` line it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'x' of object #< Object> is not a function

and it was ok when it was just:

```
class Planet
  constructor: (p5, opts) ->
    @x = opts.x
    @y = opts.y
    @diameter = opts.diameter
    @selected = false
```

i.e. before making it a child of a more generic `GameObject`... I have tried some rearrangements to make it work, but all invain. Not sure if it relates to CoffeeScript or JavaScript. The "try CoffeScript" thing on the official website spots no errors here. Browser is Chrome... What is wrong here and how do I overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing commas to separate the arguments:

```
super (p5 opts.x opts.y)
```

should be

```
super (p5, opts.x, opts.y)
```

Otherwise, that line is interpreted as `super(p5(opts.x(opts.y)))`, hence the "not a function" error.

Answer (score 2):

don't you just want

`super p5, opts.x, opts.y`

[Here is a link to your code running with no errors](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20GameObject%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@p5,%20@x,%20@y%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20@selected%20=%20false%0A%0Aclass%20Planet%20extends%20GameObject%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20%28p5,%20opts%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20super%20p5,%20opts.x,%20opts.y%0A%20%20%20%20@diameter%20=%20opts.diameter%0A%0Ap5%20=%20%27p5%27%0Aplanet%20=%20new%20Planet%20p5,%20%7Bx%3a%20100,%20y%3a%20100,%20diameter%3a%2020%7D%0A%0Aalert%20%22#%7Bplanet%7D%22).